# sale el error "file format not recognized; treating as linker script" al ejecutar un programa simple en C++ en VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

aun soy un poco nuevo en esto de la programación y me encontré en este problema, verán estoy empezando a programar en C++ en Visual Studio y cuando quiero ejecutar un simple programa de "Hola mundo" recibo esta salida que no tiene que ver con el código que escribí:
[image: Salida al ejecutar el código]

Ya revise desde MSY2 MINGW64 que instale los paquetes de gcc, g++ y gdp (el debugger) que pedía el video que ví y creo que fueron los correctos (video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HD0pqVtsmw&t=941s).
¿Será esto un problema con la instalación de VS?¿algo que tengo que cambiar en la configuración?¿u otra cosa? he visto que recominedan mucho esta plataforma como recurso, muchas gracias de antemano.
El código escrito:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Hola mundo!!!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El problema no lo tiene Visual Studio. Es posible que haya algo mal configurado.

Comment: revisaste tu path?...